# Ecto: associated values provided to inputs_for have different order

Tags: forms, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have two schemas with has_many relation. 
Post:

```
  schema "blog_posts" do
    field :body, :string
    has_many :notes, MyProject.Blog.Note, foreign_key: :blog_post_id
    timestamps()
  end
```

and Note:

```
  schema "blog_notes" do
    field :title, :string
    belongs_to :post, MyProject.Blog.Post, foreign_key: :blog_post_id
    timestamps()
  end
```

In the PostController for edit action I load the post with associated notes:

```
  def edit(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    post = Repo.get!(Post, id) |> Repo.preload(:notes)
    IO.inspect post
    changeset = Blog.change_post(post)
    render(conn, "edit.html", post: post, changeset: changeset)
  end
```

The form template looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :body, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= textarea f, :body, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :body %>
  </div>

  <%= inputs_for f, :tags, fn fa -> %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label fa, :title, class: "control-label" %>
        <%= text_input fa, :title, class: "form-control" %>
        <%= error_tag fa, :title %>
      </div>    
    <%= end %>
  <%= end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that when I open post edit form with some notes added it presents notes in order different from they were added, it seems that Ecto preloads associated notes not taking care about the order. Is there easy way to make Ecto to get saved associated models in the order they were added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a query to `Repo.preload` to do this:

```
notes = from(n in MyProject.Blog.Note, order_by: n.inserted_at)
post = Repo.get!(Post, id) |> Repo.preload(notes: notes)
```

This will load the `notes` ordered by `inserted_at` in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks, it's so elegant. Great to see there is the way to continue using preload function for such cases.